# torch.cuda.is_available() returns True in one environment but False in another

Tags: pytorch

I have pytorch cuda installed in a conda environment (env A). I created another conda environment (env B) and tried installing pytorch cuda the same way but torch.cuda.is_available() returns False.

In (env B) I installed pytorch using the following command:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

I prompts the following:

[image: Output of the installation command]

[image: Can't find cuda]

Interestingly, the same command returns True in env A where I previously installed pytorch cuda but returns False in env B.

If I clone env A to create env B then I can access the pytorch gpu. But I don't want to clone it because it will contain unnecessary packages.

Since it perfectly cuda 11.7 perfectly works in my other environment (env A), I know it is compatible with mu GPU.

Comment: check environment variables, 
`set |grep -Pi "nvid|torch|path|LD"`

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for that and hard to tell which one;

1. Make sure you are running the code within the activated environment (envB), PyTorch with CUDA is installed. Not base.
2. Verify that you have installed CUDA properly in envB, if not use following to install cudatoolkit 11.7 in the envB

> ```
> conda install cudatoolkit=11.7 -c nvidia
> ```

3. Ensure that the CUDA toolkit path is correctly set in environment variables of envB. The PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables should include the paths to the CUDA.